# web3j transactions with value

Tags: erc-20, web3j

I'm using web3j to analyze transactions.
How can I get transactions of a specific contract (assuming I got it's address) in some time frame (or blocks interval) and how can I know if ERC20 tokens were transferred in a transaction once I get it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an API like the [one](https://etherscan.io/apis) provided by EtherScan or get an Infura account, but, alas, these are centralised solutions.

A fully decentralised method would be to run a full node and use the [JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) commands.

Now you can query the list of transactions for your contract address. You can take their inputs and decode them, provided you have the contract's ABI. Here's some [sample code](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/contractz/blob/master/js/decoder.js) doing that for an [ERC20 transaction](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xc2f4d23d28f10b2986e16490db10f8fcfb571b6ad28e2f7345e09b685e2d215f) on Ropsten.

If you know the contract adheres to the ERC20 standard and the name of the function is `transfer` when the input is decoded, that's an ERC20 token transfer.

Comment: Thanks, I'm asking though specifically about a web3j (Java implementation) method of doing that.

Comment: I see, it might be worthwhile to mention you're looking for an implementation per se.

Comment: The title and the question body mention "web3j", which is a java implementation for web3. You might have missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this with Web3J is something like

```
Optional<TransactionReceipt> transaction = web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(transactionHash).send().getTransactionReceipt();
assert transaction.isPresent();
String toAddress = transaction.get().getTo();
```